# 2020 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Skeptics's [third moderator election](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: tim] [image: fredsbend]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6700523114725376/0).

Comment: Congratulations @fedsbend & @tim!

Comment: Congratulations to you both. Welcome aboard!

Comment: Congrats folks! Have fun and keep on making the sites better!

Comment: Oh, I got my preferences (:

Comment: How you as a moderator and manager have this low reputation count?!

Answer (score 14):

Thank you, community, for voting me in. Though I'm quite certain my win here is largely due to a small nomination list, you have my promise to work for the benefit of this community and site. What that means exactly is that I will always be in consideration for site quality and upholding site policies.

[I promised three areas of focus in my nomination](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-47974): 1) Political questions/answers need dedicated policies to improve quality, 2) HNQ as currently affecting this site is overall harmful, so we need to do something about it, 3) meta participation is too low and needs to be increased. If you believe I am not living up to those promises, call me out on it.

For starting out, I'll be running on WWOJD: What would Oddthinking and Jamiec do? I need to learn the mod tools, understand the nuance of their mod decisions, and build trust and rapport with them. For at least a few weeks, I'll be emulating them in every way.

Comment: Congrats fredsbend! I missed this election result, well deserved!